# Html character encoding with PrimeNG p-table

Tags: html, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

In our Angular project, although we have defined all the necessary character notations in the related html files, we cannot manage to display some characters that can be displayed in UTF-8 in all of the MVC projects where PrimeNG is not used.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    ...
    //code omitted for brevity
<head>
```

Is there any solution to define character encoding globally when using PrimeNG. I have seen this problem with **p-table** component.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a character please ?

Comment: @Antikhippe ı,ñ for example. On the other and opening these files using Notepad++ I see that encoding is UTF-8 BOM. If I change the encoding to UTF-8 and save them, the problem is solved. But I need a better and global way to fix this problem.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1161277/can-notepad-convert-multiple-opened-files-to-ansi-encoding) could help you... ?

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Yes, i would be useful but I am looking a global fix programmatically.